# In PHP, how do I call master class functions to different pages?

Tags: php

I have master class for the whole project. I need to call master class functions to different pages and methods as described below:

Master.php

```
class master{

    function login_parser(){

    }
}
```

Index.php

```
include('master.php')

function test(){
    $obj = new master();
}

function test2(){
    obj = new master();
}
```

I need to call object for every method. Is there any way to call an object in single time?

Comment: This should be asked on StackOverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

You could give that object as a parameter to the function, so it's also clear that there is a dependency to this object which can also be typehinted (which gets lost if just using it via global)

```
$obj = new master();

function test(master $obj) {
  ...
}
```

and then call:

```
test($obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to achieve this

Tobias Zander gave the option of parameters (dependency injection)

pros: know what the function needs

cons: could end up with giving a lot of parameters to a function

```
$obj = new master();

function test(master $obj) {
  ...
}
```

The second way could be using globals

pros: no paramter chain

cons: don't know what dependencies the function has

```
$obj = new master();

function test(){
    global $obj; //Now carry on
}
```

The third way, singleton

pros: object orientated way

cons: dont know the dependencies

In this your master class needs a static function that returns itself

```
class Master
    {
    protected static $master ;

    public static function load()
    {
        if(!self::$master instanceof Master) {
            self::$master = new Master();
        }

        return self::$master;
    }
}
```

Now i can use the master every where in my script using the load function, and it will only be initiated once

```
function test()
{
    $master = Master::load();
}
```

I personaly use method 1, but than for a class
    class Test
    {
        protected $master;

```
    public function __construct(Master $master) 
    {
        $this->master = $master;
    }

    public function whoo()
    {
        // now I can use $this->master as the master class
    }
}
```

Comment: Good description of options. I think you will find modern programming trend slanted towards dependency (the option you noted as your own personal preference).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Instead of creating object everytime. Create on outside the functions on global scope.

```
include('master.php')
$obj = new master();

function test(){
    global $obj; //Now carry on
}

function test2(){
    global $obj;
}
```

Comment: Relying on `global` is really poor programming practice.  If a function call requires an object, you should inject that dependency into the function as a parameter.